# converting python data to json and sending it as response to axios function

Tags: json, django, axios, response

```
print(type(json.dumps(res)))
print(json.dumps(res))
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(res), content_type="application/json")
```

output:

[[5671, 204], [5673, 192], [5674, 120], [5683, 120], [5684, 192], [5685, 204]]

res is simple list , i am using this response in axios and it is array . 
what i don't understand how json.dump(res) is returning json object , it is simple str . 
json should be "key" : "value". Can some help me to understand this please.

Comment: `json.dumps` does not return a JSON object, it returns a string. It is not entirely clear to me what the issue is however?

Comment: thanks Willem for replying .  what i don't understand in AJAX , I am using axios , axios should get json in http response right , if this is string it is like axios internally covert it into javascript object ? what i learned so far is that we convert json to javascript object and then we can use it .

Comment: JSON can be an array or an object or any valid javascript type, it does not necessarily need to be "key/value".

Comment: Use Django rest framework it is easy. What is your json response looks like? with your key and value

Comment: Iain - can you give me reference where i can read about different type of json objects .

Comment: @GorkhaliKhadka - print(json.dumps(res)) : - response is [[5671, 204], [5673, 192], [5674, 120], [5683, 120], [5684, 192], [5685, 204]] , it is a json object ?